# Xcode is losing colours and auto complete

Tags: xcode

Using `Xcode 7.3` , sometimes randomly the editor turns to be black, no syntax colours , but worse- no auto complete for local variables and functions.

When you compile again, **you get the colours back** , but still no auto complete.
Sometimes there is a message that there is a problem with the editor.

I did not have this problem before (5 years), and I'v read this thread which does not seems like the same problem, because its too old :
[Xcode: code loses syntax coloring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138047/xcode-code-loses-syntax-coloring)

This might seems like a small thing, but without the auto-complete -its really hell !

Comment: Things to consider: 1: Uninstalling all of Xcode (from all it's folders dotted about the place) and reinstalling. 2: Try the beta and see if it fixes this problem, you can use them side-by-side without having to remove your existing Xcode. 3: It might be time to reinstall a fresh OS with a fresh Xcode. A fresh OS can work wonders for many odd quirks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 7.3 Syntax Highlighting and Code Completion issues with Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165865/xcode-7-3-syntax-highlighting-and-code-completion-issues-with-swift)

Comment: You are not alone ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is common issue. any chance you are coding in Swift? i think it is still kind of unstable.

but you can try

**1) delete module cache**

> it is within the same folder as project's derived data. when syntax highlighting stops working, try to delete it. quit xcode
>   and delete **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache** directory

**2) clean project**

> try clean with **⌘ + ⇧ + K** and then with **⌥ + ⌘ + ⇧ + K**

**3) restart xcode**

Comment: Thanks, I also found out that it happens when there is no internet connection for a few moments , I am certainly sure there is some relation between the two