# Xcode 9 code completion and highlighting not working

Tags: xcode, xcode9

I have seen many threads about this online, but not for `Xcode 9`. For some reason code completion and syntax highlighting is no longer working. Last week it was fine.

Using the GM build.

Anyone have this issue or know how to resolve it? A restart of Xcode and my computer did not help.

Comment: fwiw I'm seeing the same thing. Don't remember this from the beta either. Hopefully fixed in next version.

Comment: Happens for me on just one project, and syntax coloring is also incomplete. When I open any other project it works fine.

Comment: Xcode 9 is always crashing the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Finder I navigated to user->Library->Developer->Xcode->DerivedData and deleted the subfolder of the project in question. After next build of the project the syntax highlighting and code completion returned.

Comment: Derived data strikes again!

Comment: What an absolute joke that this is still routinely necessary after years. They might as well have a dedicated button for it next to the Build and Run button.

Answer (score 7):

In my situation, there are a few of .swift files not working. I've overcome by removing these files from project and re-adding them back.

Comment: I have to remove folder group and add them again.

Comment: Same here. This happened for me because i renamed a file. Deleting the reference and then re-adding ti worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Quitting Xcode then reopening it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work again, I have to restart the macOS System.
I'm using Xcode 11.0 (11A420a), at the same time, Xcode 10 works OK.
So I think there is some process does not work, which should work for code coloring.

Answer (score 0):

For me, code completion/highlighting not working due to the missing file in the Compile Sources under Build Phases. I added that file and it works.

Hope this helps anyone.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I have observed the same problem while writing in swift on xcode 9.0, Seems it is fixed in 9.1 i am using 9.1 which is fine, please update xcode to 9.1 or newer.

Comment: I don't think so, I'm using Xcode 9.1 and issue sometimes turn back